# How to handle hybrid app version numbers

Tags: cordova, versioning, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm asking myself how to handle version numbers when building an hybrid application for multiple targets like android, ios and web. Normally you have one semantic version, e.g. 1.0.0 for a typical web application. But if I create an hybrid application based on the web application I would go ahead and give this container another version. And if I just fix issues regarding one platform in this hybrid app I would need to give each platform another version.

You see I'm a bit confused. Maybe someone that has already implemented such an workflow can tell me how to handle version numbers when building an application for multiple targets?

Comment: See my post (the first part): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572817/xcode-7-2-build-settings-for-ionic-app-keep-getting-reset/34573726#34573726

Comment: My question is not about how to set a version for an hybrid application. It is about how to handle multiple versions (one web-version, one android-version, one ios-version, etc.). Please re-read my question.